# Calculo de porcentagem

Tags: php

Na minha loja virtual eu possuo a seguinte opção ex: de 1.119,00 por 999,00 o preço atual e o preço do desconto, como posso estar sabendo quantos porcentos a pessoa esta economizando com a compra ? tipo quantos porcentos de desconto a compra tem ? usando o campo de valor antigo e valor novo, abraço

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo da seguinte forma:

```
(V2-V1)/V1 × 100 = PORCENTAGEM
```

Vamos dizer que você tem um item que tem o valor de R$50 e com o desconto ficou R$20 então colocamos da seguinte forma:

```
((20 – 50)/50) × 100 = PORCENTAGEM

(-30/50) × 100 = PORCENTAGEM

-0,60 × 100 = -60%
```

Em PHP:

```
$valorAntigo = 50;
$valorNovo   = 20;

$Porcentagem = (($valorNovo - $valorAntigo)/$valorAntigo)*100;
```